# Gay marriage wedding cake (permitted to bake/inscribe?)

Tags: halacha, wedding

With regards to this ruling in Northern Ireland:

http://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/may/19/northern-ireland-ashers-baking-company-guilty-discrimination-gay-marriage-cake

The baker who refused to put the writing on the cake was Christian, but what would be the halachic situation if a Jewish baker was asked to make such a cake and put such an inscription on it.

In addition, would it be permissible to make a cake for a gay wedding even if you were not expected to put on any inscription. (Avodah Zara first mishnah suggests it is forbidden to perform trade with people for the sake of idolatrous practice, and whilst this is not idolatrous it may still be forbidden by extension if you know the cake is for that use).

Comment: That question is more general. The big issue was that the cake manufacturer here was asked to write an inscription that he did not believe in.

Comment: That question specifically asks about baking a custom cake.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer answers it. In any case this is a disturbing case. I would also refuse to put that on a cake. I would however sell them a cake and let them write it on themselves.

Comment: If you want better answers to that question you may consider offering a bounty on it.

Comment: Due to the sectarian history of Northern Ireland, they have specific rules against religious bigotry or discrimination. The case might not have reached the same conclusion in other parts of the UK. That said, I do not find the case "disturbing".